# How to fetch data between two time based on current time in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my sample data

[image: Sample Image]

Thease data are the doctor appointment time(fromTime and ToTime)

how to get the doctors availability based on current time?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have start and end times for shifts with the times spanning midnight in some cases.  You can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where (fromtime < totime and 
       convert(time, getdate()) >= fromtime and
       convert(time, getdate()) < totime
      ) or
      (fromtime > totime and 
       convert(time, getdate()) >= fromtime or
       convert(time, getdate()) < totime
      )
```